# 'Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib': Installing Tensorflow on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, apple-m1

I am trying to install Tensorflow on my MacBook Pro with the M1 chip. The operating system of my MacBook is MacOS Big Sur Version 11.0.

[image]

In order to install Tensorflow to use it with Python, I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/), which says that I have to do the following:

1. Install Homebrew.
2. Download MiniForge3 for macOS arm64 chips (link provided in the webpage).
3. Install MiniForge3 using:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
   sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
   source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
   ```
4. Create a folder to set up an environment for Tensorflow.

   ```
   mkdir tensorflow-test
   cd tensorflow-test
   ```
5. Make and activate Conda environment.

   ```
   conda create --prefix ./env python=3.9.7
   conda activate ./env
   ```
6. Install Tensorflow dependencies.

   ```
   conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
   python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
   python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
   ```

After this, I open a Jupyter Notebook and I try to import tensorflow, but this error shows up:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/blancoarnau/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../core/platform/_cpu_feature_guard.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNKSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE3strEv
   Referenced from: /Users/blancoarnau/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../core/platform/_cpu_feature_guard.so (which was built for Mac OS X 12.3)
   Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
```

As you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: does updating to  Mac OS X 12.3 work @Arnau?

Comment: @yts61 Yes, it does!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check the message details:
(which was built for ***Mac OS X 12.3***)

you need to upgrade macOS to 12.3

Comment: Does it working after updating?? Can anyone tell

Comment: @RanaBest, did you try?

Comment: Yes, I did and it worked!

Comment: I confirm that this solution works.